# Formatting PHP Echo in Table

Tags: php, echo

I have some coding in my website that retrieves data from a MySQL database.

```
   <?php echo "<b><h6 id='lp2'><div id='rpc'> $channel_name</div></h6></b><p />";?>
```

Also, I have this code:

```
<body style="overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:scroll">
```

What I want to do is, make all the echo'd posts be displayed on top of each other, in 2 rows. Kinda like a table.

```
Post   Post   Post   ...
Post   Post   Post   ...
```

How would I style the MySQL output this way for echoing?

Comment: please learn css\html `<b><h6 id='lp2'><div id='rpc'>` is terrible

Comment: target all divs, and make then inline: `..{display:inline; float:left}`

Comment: So, Should I apply that code to #rpc? @ Qǝ uoɯᴉs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .items {
        display: inline; /* puts all on the same line */
        float: left; /* keeps putting the items to the left */
      }
      .reset {
        clear: both; /* resets the 'float: left', thus starting a new line */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $link = mysqli_connect(); // enter connection code here
      $query = "select `channel_name` from `your_table` ..."; // enter query here
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // execute query
      $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // count rows
      $i = 0; // start counting to see if we have passed half way
      while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { // for each row ...
        $channel_name = htmlspecialchars($obj->channel_name); // escape results
        echo '<div class="items">' . $channel_name . '</div>'; // output values
        if (++$i > $num_rows / 2) { // if we passed half way ...
          echo '<div class="reset"></div>'; // finish first row
          $i = -1; // and prevent entering this if again
        }
      }
      echo '<div class="reset"></div>'; // finish second row
      mysqli_free_result($result); // free results from memory
      mysqli_close($link); // close db connection
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```